# Telegraf.js pass data from button to a function that handle a WizardScene

Tags: node.js, telegraf, telegram-api, telegraf.js

I need to pass some data retrieved from a Database.

When i click into a button i send a private message to the user who have cliecked. I need to pass some datas from that button, to the message sent. Because, into that message i have an other button that starts a WizardScene. SO how can i do to pass data? Thank you.

Here is my code.

This is into a function that post a photo with a description and with a callbackup button.

```
my function() {
...
let productId = //obtain from a db;
await bot.telegram.sendPhoto(
      channel_id,
      { source: filepath },
      {
        caption: description.join("\n"),
        parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2',
        reply_markup: productButtons.reply_markup
      }
    )
  return productId;
...}
```

and the button is:

```
const productButtons = Extra.markup((m) =>
  m.inlineKeyboard([
    [m.callbackButton('TEST', 'test_btn')],
  ])
)
```

when someone clicsk on it, it sends a message on a private user with this:

```
bot.action('testa_btn', (ctx) => {
    console.log('testa')
    let text = `My text about ${productId}`

    ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.from.id, o_functions.escapeReplace(text), {
      parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2',
      reply_markup: startBtn.reply_markup
    })
    
  });
```

this sends a text where i need to write my productid, and an other button where i start my wizard scene:

```
const startBtn = Extra.markup((m) =>
  m.inlineKeyboard([
    [m.callbackButton('START', 'start_btn_wizard')],
  ])
);

bot.action('start_btn_wizard', (ctx) => {
    return ctx.scene.enter('super-wizard');
  })
```

So how can i pass my productId variable, first to the button TEST, then to the wizard scene? I need to use it on the Wizard on the user dialogue.

THank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a couple of things to pass data from a callback button to a handler and then towards a wizard scene.

1. Add the desired data to the button. Notice how I attached the product Id to the callback data.

   ```
   const startBtn = Extra.markup((m) =>
     m.inlineKeyboard([
       [m.callbackButton('START', `start_btn_wizard_${product_id}`)],
     ])
   );
   ```
2. Receive the button callback using a regex rather than using a literal string and extract the product ID from the callback data.

   ```
   bot.action(/start_btn_wizard_+/, (ctx) => {
       let product_id = ctx.match.input.substring(17);

       // add all necessary validations for the product_id here
       return ctx.scene.enter('super-wizard');
   });
   ```
3. Pass the acquired id to the wizard scene and extract it again from inside the scene using `ctx.scene.state`.

   ```
   bot.action(/start_btn_wizard_+/, (ctx) => {
       let product_id = ctx.match.input.substring(17);

       // add all necessary validations for the product_id here
       return ctx.scene.enter('super-wizard', {product_id: product_id});
   });
   ```

From inside the wizard, you can access the product_id using `ctx.scene.state.product_id`.

Hope this helps someone even though it's probably too late for the OP

Comment: this solution will not work if `${product_id}` is large

Comment: The maximum length is of 64 bytes, usually ids are max 32 bytes.
Anyway you can edit your id system